# Visual Basic format number to hower many number on left of decimal and 1 decimal without rounding

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am acutally using SSRS but it is for an expression so this is VB code. I am wondering how I would get a number such as 236.4723423 to appear at 236.4 instead of 236.5, so basically I jsut want to truncate it always after 1 decimal.

I tried Format = "N1" this rounds it
I tried Formate = "#######.0" and "######.#" and this rounds it as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    value = Math.Floor(value * 10) / 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the format "########.00", then once it's in string form, trim the last char.

**Edit:**

```
Dim myString as String
myString = CStr(FORMAT(((SUM(Fields!Shipment_Weight.Value)) / 2000),"######.00"))
myString = myString.Substring(0, myString.Length - 1) & "T"
```

Comment: =CStr(FORMAT(((SUM(Fields!Shipment_Weight.Value)) / 2000),"######.00")) + "T"

Comment: How would I trim the last charector then add the +"T"?

Comment: @user380432: I added an edit with how I would do it (leaving your format/sum portion as is).

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to implement a custom IFormatProvider interface to do this. There is a great example on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx).